# What is the relationship between individuals fitness and their offsprings in genetic algorithm?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm

In genetic algorithm , is it the best way to have offsprings with high fitness is  to crossover with individuals with high fitness  so that the offsprings have high fitness too?  Is there any guarantee that parents with high fitness will produce offsprings with high fitness ? Any mathematical proof for this.

Comment: This question is way too general. I don't think there is a strong answer for this, and that explains the many different implementations of genetic algorithms. Some use crossover, some don't. Some always pick the best individuals as parents, some don't.

Comment: @Pablo Can you suggest some resources to read about what you just said. Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at this chapter ( https://www.cs.vu.nl/~gusz/ecbook/Eiben-Smith-Intro2EC-Ch2.pdf ).

It comes from this book ( https://www.cs.vu.nl/~gusz/ecbook/ecbook.html ). Lucky you, this chapter is a free sample!

Comment: @Pablo Thanks a lot .